# Cannot run svn update as www-data in post-commit hook

Tags: svn, debian, sudo

I'm using svn under Debian and I usually commit my web files using a certain user, which is different from www-data. 
My commit process is ok, but I want to write a post-commit hook that is capable to perform an svn update AS www-data to another working copy of the svn repository, for testing live updates of the code.

I'm trying to write the post-commit hook in this way:
 sudo -u www-data /usr/bin/svn update

Unfortunately, my working copy is not updated when the commit process is completed. But when I try to execute the former sudo statement in the CLI, the statement succeeds and the working copy is updated correctly. Have you some clue about this?

I've configured /etc/sudoers in such a way that is not necessary to type user password to execute sudo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was in the way i've configured my user in /etc/sudoers to access /usr/bin/svn as www-data. The syntax I used was completely wrong.

Now I have a group called working_copy, which comprises my commit user and www-data. In /etc/sudoers I have this line:

```
%working_copy ALL=(www-data:working_copy) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/svn
```

provided that my commit user can execute sudo with no password.

Thank you to @LazyBadger anyway!

Answer (score 0):

1. Post-* hooks in Subversion executed in **empty environment**
2. `svn up` without parameters uses `.` as target, and I can't recall current dir (if exist) for hook-process, but it is not your LIVE-WC, I suppose, so better way will be `/usr/bin/svn update /PATH/TO/LIVE`
3. You can redirect stdout|stderr into file in order to see some details later (or marshall output of hook back to your SVN-client and see hooks operations in real-time - add `1>&2` to the trailing part of command)

Comment: I put in my hook: /usr/bin/sudo -g www-data -u www-data /usr/bin/svn update FULL/PATH/TO/LIVE/WC >> /tmp/svn_log.txt . Unfortunately, this yet doesn't work and the log file is not written. the user who does the commit can execute sudo without password.

The former statement succeeds if I type it as 'commit user' from the Debian shell.